# Bug - AngularJS Service with GET JSON file

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am working on a simple sample AngularJS application that reads data from an external JSON data file. I have tried everything, and I cannot find why the application does not work. Any input would be most appreciated.

'filmCtrl' Control:

```
angular
    .module('mediaApp')
    .controller('filmCtrl', function(filmList) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.films = filmList.retrieveFilms();
    });
```

'filmList' Service:

```
angular
    .module('mediaApp')
    .service('filmList', function($http) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.retrieveFilms = function() {
            return $http
                .get('films.json')
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.films;
                });
        };

        return vm;
    });
```

JSON:

```
{
    "films":[
        {
            "title": "Reservoir Dogs",
            "director": "Quentin Tarantino",
            "year": "1992"
        },
        {
            "title": "2001: A Space Odyssey",
            "director": "Stanley Kubrick",
            "year": "1967"
        },
        {
            "title": "Memento",
            "director": "Christopher Nolan",
            "year": "2000"
        },
        {
            "title": "Enter the Dragon",
            "director": "Robert Clouse",
            "year": "1973"
        },

         [etc]...
    ]
}
```

All of these files are saved in the same folder, and have been included in my HTML file. The JSON has been validated. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: use `promise` and it will solve your problem, or you can return `$http.get('films.json')` from service and then consume it in your controller

Comment: Just to be clear, "films.json" is an endpoint on the server correct? Looks a bit like a local file which wouldn't work at all.

Comment: You always can inspect what is the object received. Just add a `console.log(response);` or `debugger;` statement in the promise `then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments you can create `service` like this -

```
mediaApp.service('filmList', ['$http',
function($http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.retrieveFilms = function() {
        return $http.get('data.json');
    };
    return vm;
}]);
```

In `controller` you can consume this `service` like -

```
mediaApp.controller('filmCtrl', function(filmList) {
    var vm = this;
    filmList.retrieveFilms().then(function(response) {
        vm.films =response.data.films;
    });
});
```

Working Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/6RVlvdh8oG5WaiEHaPdM?p=preview

It will work in **FF** but for some browsers it will throw `CORS` error so better run it on a server.

Answer (score 1):

1. In a `then(response)` the response object has these properties:

`data – {string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.

`status – {number}` – HTTP status code of the response.

`headers – {function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.

`config – {Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.

`statusText – {string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

So this should be

```
return $http
   .get('films.json')
   .then(function(response) {
      return response.data.films;
});
```

instead of

```
return $http
   .get('films.json')
   .then(function(response) {
      return response.films;
});
```

See [the official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for more info.

2. If you're not running a webserver of any kind and just testing with file://films.json, then you're probably running into same-origin policy issues. See:

http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy

Some error message could be useful.